# как работает блок synchronized и остальные нити при разных синхронизированных объектах

Tags: java

есть кусок кода:

```
public class Test {
    private final Socket socket;
    private final ObjectOutputStream out;
    private final ObjectInputStream in;

    public Connection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    public void sendSomeThing1(Message message)  {
        synchronized (out) {
            out.writeObject(message);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sendSomeThing2 (Message message)  {
            out.writeObject(message);
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в sendSomeThing1 я блокирую только объект out? Это значит, что другие нити могут использовать объект и методы класса Test.

А вот при использовании void sendSomeThing2 нити не смогут использовать методы класса TESE одновременно, будут ждать своей очереди?

Так же в чем различия между

```
synchronized (**out**) {
    out.writeObject(message);
}
```

и

```
synchronized (**this**) {
    out.writeObject(message);
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что в sendSomeThing1 я блокирую только объект
>   out? Это значит, что другие нити могут использовать объект и методы
>   класса Test.

Да.

> А вот при использовании void sendSomeThing2 нити не смогут
>   использовать методы класса TESE одновременно, будут ждать своей
>   очереди?

Не совсем так.

`synchronized` метод - это тоже самое, что сделать `synchronized (this)` внутри метода.

Другие потоки будут ждать очереди, если они обращаются к **этому** методу, **другим `synchronized` методам** или локам на `this`.

Если метод не помечен как `synchronized`, другие потоки в любое время смогут к нему обратиться, даже если какой-то `synchronized` метод залочен каким-то потоком.

> Так же в чем различия между
>
> ```
> synchronized (**out**) {
>     out.writeObject(message);
> }
>
>
>
> synchronized (**this**) {
>     out.writeObject(message);
> }
> ```

Это одно и тоже в целом. Но есть нюансы. Скажем, если это класс, реализующий логику контейнера/коллекции, у него есть методы на чтение и на запись. По логике позволительно читать и писать туда одновременно. Если вы оба методы `get`/`set` залочите на `this`, то запись будет ждать окончания чтения и наоборот. В таких случаях можно создать два разных объекта. Запись лочить по одному из них, чтение по другому.